# Linux 'make' command fails after installing ruby and gems for biopieces

Tags: make, ruby

We wanted to try the [biopieces tools](https://code.google.com/p/biopieces/), which require certain dependencies, such as ruby and perl, a.o.
After running the [installers](https://code.google.com/p/biopieces/downloads/list), and consequently installing some ruby gems, we were not able to run our regular linux 'make' command anymore:

```
~$ make

/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make:1:in `top (required)>': uninitialized constant ELF (NameError)
        from /usr/local/bin/make:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/make:23:in `<main>'
```

If we specify the root directory /usr/bin/make, it does work.

For now, we are not using biopieces and we could uninstall everything.
Is it possible to fix this, to get back where we were before?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at `ruby_installer.sh` in the links you mentioned, you'll see that it ends with:

```
echo "All done. Now append the following to your ~/.bashrc file:"
echo "export PATH=\"$ruby_dir/bin:\$PATH\""
echo "Done"
```

That means that `$ruby_dir/bin` (example: `/usr/local/myruby/bin`) is now the first place where the shell will try to find programs.

To change that, just echo your PATH variable and change it so `/usr/local/myruby/bin` will be the last place to check. For example:

```
# echo $PATH
/usr/local/myruby/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin

# export PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/myruby/bin

# echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/usr/local/myruby/bin
```

And don't forget to change back the PATH in your `.bashrc` as specified in the script.

Comment: `ruby_dir="$HOME/ruby_install"` but message comes from `/usr/local/bin/make`

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin I think the first comes from `/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/make-0.3.1/bin/make`. Maybe there are some symlinks or scripts calling `/usr/local/bin/make`. The best would be to have the output of `which make`, then we'd see clearer.

Comment: I suppose that there is a script `/usr/local/bin/make` and `/usr/local/bin`  appears before `/usr/bin` in `PATH`

Comment: message comes from [make](https://rubygems.org/gems/make). @fibar Try `gem uninstall -a -x make; hash -r;`

Comment: @EvgenyVereshchagin `gem uninstall -a -x make; hash -r;` solved it. Should I answer this post with the solution to finish?

Comment: @fibar, good! see http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer . And don't use strange Ruby installers. See: [rvm](https://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv)

Answer (score 0):

Combining the Answer&Comments we received, we got it solved. First we confirmed that 'make' was being invoked from `/usr/local/bin`, which appeared before `/usr/bin` in `PATH` indeed. And then we removed the ruby 'make' from `/usr/local/bin`. Here's the step by step:

```
$ which make
$ echo $PATH
$ gem uninstall -a -x make; hash -r;
```

Now our Linux 'make' is working as usual ;-)